# Can I remove BindingRedirects from app.config c#/visual studio 2019?

Tags: app-config, assembly-binding-redirect

Is it safe to remove <bindingredirects...> from app.config when one or more assemblies aren't referenced?
For example, I've several referring to Telerik in one of my app.configs after removing all the Telerik modules from project references.
The problem I'm seeing at release build, is that the main app is trying to find the mediafoundation dll mentioned below and falls over.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1" /></startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Telerik.WinControls" publicKeyToken="5bb2a467cbec794e" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2023.1.314.40" newVersion="2023.1.314.40" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="TelerikCommon" publicKeyToken="5bb2a467cbec794e" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2023.1.314.40" newVersion="2023.1.314.40" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-13.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-15.0.0.0" newVersion="15.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Telerik.Windows.MediaFoundation" publicKeyToken="5803cfa389c90ce7" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2022.2.502.40" newVersion="2022.2.502.40" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```